# very simple JNI, don't know why java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am learning JNI and wrote a very simple JNI.

I want to access the field of Java object.

I compile on android 4.4.3 r1 source code.

But when I run it on AVD or Nexus 7 2013, I got the same error:

```
08-02 21:54:06.653: V/SimJni-JNI(1350): [development/cac-practice-android/SimJni/jni/cac_practice_simjni.cpp:15].!@#.enter.
08-02 21:54:06.653: W/dalvikvm(1350): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchFieldError; thrown while initializing Lcac/practice/SimJni;
08-02 21:54:06.653: D/AndroidRuntime(1350): Shutting down VM
08-02 21:54:06.663: W/dalvikvm(1350): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a42ba8)
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): Process: cac.practice, PID: 1350
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='mIntField' signature='I' in class Lcac/practice/SimJni;
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at cac.practice.SimJni.native_init(Native Method)
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at cac.practice.SimJni.<clinit>(SimJni.java:8)
08-02 21:54:06.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at cac.practice.SimJniActivity.onCreate(SimJniActivity.java:18)
```

Here is my code:
JNI code: cac_practice_simjni.cpp

```
#define LOG_NDEBUG  0
#define LOG_TAG "SimJni-JNI"
#include <utils/Log.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <JNIHelp.h>
#include <android_runtime/AndroidRuntime.h>

using namespace android;

static const char* const kClassSimJni = "cac/practice/SimJni";

static void cac_practice_simjni_native_init(JNIEnv *env)
{
    ALOGV("[%s:%d].!@#.enter.",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("cac/practice/SimJni");
    jfieldID intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mIntField", "I");
}

static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
    {
        "native_init",
        "()V",
        (void *)cac_practice_simjni_native_init
    },
};

int register_cac_practice_simjni(JNIEnv *env)
{
    return AndroidRuntime::registerNativeMethods(env, kClassSimJni, gMethods, NELEM(gMethods));

}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    jint result = -1;

    if (vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        ALOGE("[%s:%d].!@#.GetEnv failed.",__FILE__,__LINE__);
        goto bail;
    }
    assert(env != NULL);

    if (register_cac_practice_simjni(env) < 0) {
        ALOGE("[%s:%d].!@#.SimJni native registration failed.",__FILE__,__LINE__);
        goto bail;
    }

    // success, return valid version number
    result = JNI_VERSION_1_4;

bail:
    return result;
}
```

SimJni.java:

```
package cac.practice;

import android.util.Log;

public class SimJni {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("simjni_jni");
        native_init();
    }

    private static final String TAG = "SimJni";
    private int mIntField;

    private static native void native_init();
}
```

In OnCreate() of SimJniActivty.java, I wrote:

```
SimJni mSimJni = new SimJni();
```

**mIntField** is an **integer** field of SimJni.java,
so I don't know what's wrong with

jfieldID intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "**mIntField**", "**I**"); in cac_practice_simjni.cpp

---

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass(kClassSimJni);
if (clazz == NULL) {
    ALOGE("[%s:%d].!@#.clazz == NULL.",__FILE__,__LINE__);
}
if (intFieldID == 0) {
    ALOGV("[%s:%d].!@#.call GetFieldID().",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mIntField", "I");
}
```

I check the return value of FindClass() and it is not null.

I modified code to try other Java class:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("android/media/MediaScanner");
intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mNativeContext", "I");
```

then it pass and no error.

I think the code is corret:

```
intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mIntField", "I");
```

that SimJni.java actually has an integer field named "mIntField".

**I think the problem is JNI doesn't recognize the content of "cac.practice.SimJni".
I put SimJni.java under apk source code path: SimJni/src/cac/practive/.**

Is there any path setting which should be added to Android.mk (for build libsimjni_jni.so)?
Then JNI can recognize cac.practice.SimJni as well as android.media.MediaScanner.

**2014/08/06**

I do another test:

I moved SimJni.java to 
android/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/
and modify the package to android.media,
then I recompile framework.jar and framework2.jar.

So SimJni.java is included in framework.jar/framework2.jar.

Modify jni code to:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("android/media/SimJni");
intFieldID = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mIntField", "I");
```

It works and no error.

Comment: Before calling `GetFieldID()`, check that `FindClass()` returned not NULL.

Comment: @AlexCohn The error message makes it clear that it didn't return `null`. Otherwise where did it get `L/cac/practice/SimJNI;` from?

Comment: I suggest you recompile everything and try again. But it's rather strange to be accessing a non-static field in a static initialization method.

Comment: Thanks Alex and EJP for you comments!

Comment: @EJP There's nothing strange about it at all. The OP isn't accessing the field. He or she is simply finding its identifier.

Comment: @cac2966 Just a guess: try changing the Java code to make the field public. The Android compiler might have decided that, since the class doesn't actually use the field, it can be removed. If the field is public it wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Tested this scenario, works like charm even from inside static constructor.

Comment: @pburka I try change the field to public, the result is still the same.

Comment: You should not use internal libraries like **AndroidRuntime** unless absolutely necessary. You should use [`env->RegisterNatives()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734) instead of the non-standard wrapper, see also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/K2jL3R3vOVw).